# Find package names to launch via Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, package

How do we make an app to be universal as to be able to launch other apps on various devices?

An app has different package names on different devices.
So the question is how do we create a Universal app to call these apps regardless of their platform?

For instance let's say I have IMO installed on my phone and want my App to be able to launch IMO. Or another issue that I saw is Gallery. I launched it on one phone but the package name was different on another phone! So how are we supposed to write an app to launch other Apps and work on most platforms?

Comment: Excuse me, how many questions here? I count at least three and they are too broad IMO. Can you: a) narrow the topic, b) provide code example?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your reply. Question has to do with finding the right app name. If I want to say launch IMO on all platforms, how to do it. Coz on 2 android phones that I looked at they are called differently! This is true on most apps. I was trying Calculator. Same thing. They are not the same name on different platforms. I will list the Calculator Example here:

```
   Intent launchIntent = 
   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.doro.apps.calculator");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
            // startActivity(launchIntent);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        } // in case Instagram not installed in your device
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("openCalCulator", "Intent is null");
    }
}
```

You can see this is too specific:    com.doro.apps.calculator
If the simple calculator is called with different names, i can only imagine other apps will have different names as well.

```
I tried using getPackageManager but youtube got started instead of calculator!

    items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    pm = getPackageManager();
    packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (PackageInfo pi : packs)
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
        map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
        items.add(map);
    }
```